Asymptotic Expansion of Legendre Function of the Second Kind
I am currently studying the computation of Neron's local heights at the Archimedean places (c.f. Gross-Zagier), and it used the following asymptotic expansion as $t\rightarrow 1^+$ and for the Legendre function of the second kind $Q_{s-1}(t)$
$$Q_{s-1}(t)=\frac{1}{2}\log \frac{t+1}{t-1}-(\Gamma'/\Gamma(s)-\Gamma'/\Gamma(1))+O(1).$$
Note here $s\in \mathbb{C}$. Recall that the Legendre function is defined by
$$Q_{s-1}(t)=\int_0^{\infty}(t+\sqrt{t^2-1}\cosh u)^{-s} du$$ for $t>1$ and $s>0$
or
$$Q_{s-1}(t)=\frac{\Gamma(s)^2}{2\Gamma(2s)}(\frac{2}{1+t})^sF(s,s;2s;\frac{2}{1+t})$$
for $t>1, s\in \mathbb{C}$ and $F(a,b;c;z)$ is the hypergeometric function. I wonder how such an asymptotic expansion can be derived from the definitions. Thanks in advance for any help.

What's your question?

I have edited the post.

Let's denote $t=1+\delta$, then
$$Q_{s-1}(t)=\int_0^{\infty}(t+\sqrt{t^2-1}\cosh u)^{-s} du=\int_0^{\infty}(1+\delta+\sqrt{\delta(2+\delta)}\cosh u)^{-s} du$$
To find the first (divergent) and the second (constant) terms of the asymptotic at $\delta\to 0$ it is enough to consider
$$I=\int_0^1(1+\sqrt{2\delta}\cosh u)^{-s}du$$
$\quad$ - analysis show that other parts of the integral give $\sim\delta\ln\delta\,$ contribution and, therefore, tend to zero at $\delta\to0$.
Denoting for a while $\sqrt{2\delta}=\epsilon$ and making the substitution $x=\cosh u$
$$I=\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+\epsilon x)^s\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}}=2\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{(1+\epsilon+\epsilon t^2 )^s\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
With the same level of accuracy we can take in the denominator $1+\epsilon\approx 1$. Making the substitution $t=\frac x{\sqrt\epsilon}$
$$I\sim 2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^s\sqrt{t^2+2\epsilon}}\overset{IBP}{=}2\frac{\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+2\epsilon})}{(1+x^2)^s}\bigg|_0^\infty+4s\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+2\epsilon})}{(1+x^2)^{s+1}}xdx$$
The last integral converges at $\epsilon=0$. As we want to find only divergent and constant terms, we put $\epsilon =0$ in the last term
$$I\sim-2\ln\sqrt{2\epsilon}+4s\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln 2+\ln x}{(1+x^2)^{s+1}}xdx=-2\ln\sqrt{2\epsilon}+2\ln2+s\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln t}{(1+t)^{s+1}}dt$$
The last integral is
$$s\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln t}{(1+t)^{s+1}}dt=s\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\bigg|_{a=0}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^a}{(1+t)^{s+1}}dt$$
$$=s\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\bigg|_{a=0}B(1+a;s-a)=\frac s{\Gamma(1+s)}\big(\Gamma'(1)\Gamma(s)-\Gamma'(s)\big)=\psi(s)-\gamma$$
Using $\epsilon=\sqrt{2\delta}$
$$\boxed{\,\,Q_{s-1}(t)=\frac12\ln\frac1\delta+\frac12\ln2-\psi(s)-\gamma+o(1)\,\,}$$
Numeric check (WA) confirms the result.

One more beautiful answer !

C'est mon plaisir.  Merci :)

@Svyatoslav Thank you so much for your answer.

Thank you for the interesting question :)
